# How can I set wsd to active worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub CreatePivot()

Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
****Set WSD = Worksheets("1712")****
```

How can I set it to active Worksheet rather than set for a static Worksheet such as **1712** ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set wsd = ActiveSheet

Comment: HI just tried control and space feature , and it gave me a list of options including activeworkseet. Just wanted to post I found the answer , but the forum is so fast that the answer was already there. Thanks Tim .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the active Worksheet is in the workbook containing macros.

```
Sub CreatePivot()

Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Set WSD = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: That's true if "current" means "workbook containing macros", but not true if "current" means "workbook currently active".